# issue uploading excel source into table

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, sql-server-2008

I'm struggling to upload an `excel file` into a table using `SSIS`. I got the following warning message while I'm in the wizard

> The current user is not an owner of the selected database. This might
>   cause some operations with this database to fail

and when I proceed with the upload it runs OK except when it gets to the copying part where I get the following error messages.  `

> Copying to [dbo].[RIP_Cost_Centre$] (Error) Messages •    Error
>   0xc0202009: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An
>   OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005. An OLE DB record is
>   available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0" 
>   Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "The INSERT permission was denied on
>   the object 'RIP_Cost_Centre$', database 'MD_Roster_Optimisation',
>   schema 'dbo'.".  (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)   •    Error
>   0xc0209029: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "input "Destination Input"
>   (51)" failed because error code 0xC020907B occurred, and the error row
>   disposition on "input "Destination Input" (51)" specifies failure on
>   error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified
>   component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more
>   information about the failure.  (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard) 
>   Error 0xc0047022: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component
>   "Destination - RIP_Cost_Centre$" (38) failed with error code
>   0xC0209029 while processing input "Destination Input" (51).

The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.  (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard), and not paste the data. I've checked the mappings and they appear correct but I'm at a loss

Comment: `"The INSERT permission was denied on the object 'RIP_Cost_Centre$', database 'MD_Roster_Optimisation', schema 'dbo'."` Seems clear enough. You do not have permission to INSERT.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do away with the SSIS thing and just use Excel and SQL Server.  Please take a look at this link and you will find many ways to move data between Excel and SQL Server...or...vice versa...

http://www.excel-sql-server.com/excel-sql-server-import-export-using-vba.htm#Introduction